# export data from sqlite to Excel file in multiple tabs in python

Tags: sqlite, csv, python-2.7, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

```
......
......
ofile  = open('test.csv', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(ofile)
conn=sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("select * from emp")
mysel=c.execute("select * from emp")
for row in mysel:
    print row
    writer.writerow(row)
ofile.close()
.....
.....
```

above code is working fine and i am getting results as csv.

Problem starts when i want to write data in csv in mulitple tabs. i checked on this site and people are saying there is no option. i have to use Excel.

to get data populated in different tabs, am trying the below code with

```
import xlsxwriter
ofile = xlsxwriter.Workbook('mac.xlsx')
worksheet1 = ofile.add_worksheet()
conn=sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("select * from emp")
mysel=c.execute("select * from emp ")
for row in mysel:
    print row
    worksheet1.write("A1",row)
    #worksheet1.write(" ",row)
    #worksheet1.write(row)
ofile.close()
```

no success, please help me to sort the issue, i hope my goal (**write data in to excel from sqlite3 using python in multiple tabs**) is clear. please share your experienced thoughts

1) can i do this using xlsxwriter
2) should i use any other library 
3) is there any simple way to do it

please help

Comment: What do you mean by `multiple tabs`? Multiple worksheets? Then, how do you want to split the data into multiple sheets?

Comment: multiple tab=multiple sheets. my first problem is to write to excel and then on second stage, write to multiple sheets on the same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example how to create an excel file with multiple sheets using `xlsxwriter`:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook


workbook = Workbook('output.xlsx')
for i in range(10):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write(0, 0, "I'm sheet number %d" % (i + 1))

workbook.close()
```

Comment: thanks, but i am getting error while trying to fetch data from SQLITE. my sqlite database is simple and consist of name, age, sex, hobby

Comment: @ashirnasir well, the question was about writing to excel file..consider making another question and describe your sqlite problems there.

Comment: @ashirnasir don't close, just leave it until you'll get to the `writing to excel` step.